# Is it still possible to play AOE2: The Age of Kings over a LAN?

Tags: networking, age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

My friend and I still have copies of Age of Empires: Age of Kings and we have installed it both our laptops.

Is it still playable over LAN?

Comment: I don't see why not... have you tried it? If so and it doesn't work, what happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the old Windows 9x game, then... kind-of....

It uses an older style of LAN networking that is not used these days (I think it is IPX), and you would have difficulty installing ***and*** setting up the computers to use it. The setup required for it was picky, and I mean on Windows XP -- back when you could still easily install it! (EDIT: "easily" meaning the drivers, not the extra steps to take)

If you have Linux installed somewhere (or a modern-ish Mac) and have the Windows 9x CD of the game... I don't know how well it will work with PlayOnLinux (free) -- (PlayOnMac for Mac users, also free)

**Age of Empires 2: The Conquerors** ONLY:

> There was a custom 1.0e patcher for AoE2:TC made by a group (that could switch between that version and 1.0c), but I have no idea where it is located, and since what that 1.0e can do (allowing no CD in the drive), I cannot recommend it, and especially not link to a download... ... who knows if there even still exists a download to that patcher which isn't malware!

***Alternate solution (chosen by the asker when offered):*** Buying the Steam remake which they found on sale.

Comment: That means no? Right?

Comment: Depends on if you can find valid IPX drivers for your OS... yet there may exist a wrapper for IPX over TCP/IP

Comment: ... or is it over UDP? (dang phone sent reply before I could finish typing)

Comment: I don't understand what's that ipx whatever thing. Anyway thanks, I think we will satisfy our things on AOE3 but will miss aoe2. See if there's any other way thanks!

Comment: IPX is an old networking protocol. It is pretty much the format of how the data crosses the wire... http actually uses TCP (TCP and UDP are pretty much standard these days).

Comment: Umm ok anyway we Gonna play aoe3 lan so hope some one know about aoe2 thanks

Comment: If you two have Steam, getting AoE2 that way may be better to play it.... although I can look up that one free game similar to it, but it is slightly different.

Comment: AOE2 HD edition umm I'll think about it, its on sale too. The free game umm don't know but if it is very similar to aoe2 then go ahead and tell me!

Comment: I found it... I think... Also, not reading enough, I don't know if it is Linux-only or not (requires both base game & expansion for 9x version, or HD version on Steam) https://github.com/SFTtech/openage

Comment: So ... actually.... same thing with remade engine (and like I said, I don't know if Linux-only or not)

Comment: Its Linux only ouch

Comment: And required AoE2:TC, which you never stated you had.

Comment: Nope I have only age of kings

Comment: But the HD version... Fun Fact: they actually had to remake the graphics from scratch since they didn't have the original models they based the pixels off of in the 9x version.... and.... HD!

Comment: All add that the Steam version is an alternative to my answer (if I can now). Thank you for accepting it. :)

Answer (score 4):

I played the old version of AOE II with expansion for a long time over lan, including Windows 10. The only problems I ever had starting the game (ranging from Windows XP to Windows 10) was administrative rights for the network tool AOE II uses and fire wall blockage for which you just have to say 'Allow' and be done with it.

Make sure everybody has version 1.0c and maybe check compatibility mode.

To be honest, I have more problems with the steam version than the old version for multiplayer. The old version loads multiplayer save games nicely, but I never got that working for the steam version. I also have more problems with network stability when playing on steam compared to the old version.

Answer (score -2):

download gameranger and then you can play both aoe and aoe2 easily online.